# Rails 3: Accessing models in modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model Admin::Books, and I'd like to set an accepts_nested_attributes_for field in the :users table. I thought perhaps it'd be something like:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin_books
```

but I get the following:

> No association found for name
>   `admin_books'. Has it been
>   defined yet?

So, any suggestions on how to access a 'moduled' model from a non-moduled one?

Comment: "No joy" isn't exactly descriptive. Could you explain this a little better please?

Comment: Good point -edited above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the association like this:

```
has_many :books, :class_name => "Admin::Book"
```

Then define the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
```

This way, Rails will look to the association to get the correct class for the ANAF objects.